# Add a column in SQL query that indicates the number of times that the number is shown in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I need to make a query that selects everything from a table A, and in addition to have a column that indicates the number of times that the value of `A.col1` is in `B.col2`.

Example:

Table A:

```
id    name
1     "y"
2     "z"
3     "w"
```

Table B:

```
id     name
15     "y"
23     "w"
14     "y"
```

I want a query that will give me the following:

```
id   name      numOfTimes
1    "y"           2 // y is shown twice in table B
2    "z"           0 // z isn't shown in table B
3    "w"           1 // w is shown once in table B
```

Comment: Why use Jquery tag for a SQL question ? Did you look at "join" statement ? Or did you look at any SQL tutorial ?

Comment: sorry about the jQuery tag, I've removed it.
I've tried to use join, but I had problems. Can you please try to write a query?

Comment: Use Left Outer join (left table will be table A) and group the results and use count for aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 Select a.id, a.name, count(b.id) as numoftimes from a
 left outer join b on a.name = b.name
 group by a.id, a.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in multiple ways

```
 select a.id as Id
 ,a.name as Name
 ,(select count(1) from b where a.id=b.id) as NumberOfTimes
 from a;
```

or

```
 select a.id as Id
 ,a.name as Name
 ,count(b.id) as NumberOfTimes
 from a
 left join b on a.id=b.id;
```

Comment: the join must be on name, not id, and for second solution you need a group by

Answer (score 0):

Try with this following you will get your expected result.

select a.id,a.col1,count(b.col1) as numOfTimes

from TableA a left join TableB b

on a.col1 = b.col1

group by a.id,a.col1;

Thanks.